# how to assign different Text formats for each Long Text fields?

Tags: 7, nodes, input-formats

In my node creating form i have two `Long Text` fields, they are:

1. Article
2. Lists

[image]
And i have created two `Text Formats` they are:

1. Article
2. Lists

[image]

Now, is there any Drupal way to assign:

- `Article (field_article)` field with `Article` Text Format
- `Lists (field_lists)` field with `Lists` Text Format

If not, then how i can do it Programmatically in node `node--article.tpl.php`? or any other idea? 
- Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [better formats module](https://drupal.org/project/better_formats). The module allows you set text formats per field.

> Better formats is a module to add more flexibility to Drupal's core
>   input format system.

Comment: Does Better Formats still work for Drupal 7? Its D7 release is very old.