# Setting two default text formats for two long text fields in the same content type

Tags: theming, nodes

I need to use a specific text format (filtered html) for all user roles for one specific field in a content type and another specific text format (code) for another field in the same content type.

I [installed 'Better formats' module using the suggestion here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/83355/how-to-assign-different-text-formats-for-each-long-text-fields) but couldn't see any way to make it do what I want.

Is it possible - and if so, how - to specify a text format for each long text field so that when a user creates a new node of that content type, using the default creation form, they do not select the text type for each of those fields but it is already set for them?

Maybe it DOES use the better formats module and I just can't see how to use it. If so I'd be happy to hear what I could do with that module to solve my problem as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit each field and there should be a betters format option there.

**ex:**

Body field: Filter HTML

Code field: FULL HTML

Comment: That makes sense and worked easily. Thank you again. Nice new photo btw.